# Aplicar <title> dinámico en PHP - MVC

Tags: php, mvc

Tengo una web desarrollada en PHP en MVC, donde defino las vistas en función a una plantilla. Quiero que cada vista tenga un `<title>` diferente que venga definido por mí para cada página. Lo que he propuesto me funciona para todas páginas que vienen después de / (Ej: dominio.com/home) Mi problema viene cuando solo se consulta el dominio (Ej: dominio.com) me tira el siguiente error:

> `Notice: Undefined index: url in /opt/lampp/htdocs/xxx/cw-content/layouts/header.php on line 9`

Mi código es el siguiente: en el header.php aplico lo siguiente:

```
if ($_GET['url']=="home" || $_GET['url']=="index"){
        $title="Home";
        } if ($_GET['url']=="about") {
        $title="About";
    } else {
        $title="Otro";
    }
```

Y aplico en  la variable $title

```
<title><?php echo _($title) ?></title>
```

¿Se os ocurre como solucionar para que cuando la consulta venga sin dominio.com/xxx sino dominio.com también me resuelva el titulo?

Por otra parte si tenéis alguna otra idea de hacerlo también es bienvenida.

Comment: Independientemente de que te recomendaría algo más sencillo para ahorrar los diferentes `if`, la cuestión aquí es que desde algún contexto el dato `url` no está llegando. Hay que resolver el `Undefined index: url`, pero no explicas precisamente en qué contexto ocurre eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pare evitar el error de `Undefined index` debes comprobar previamente que exista con [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php):

Ej.

```
if (isset($_GET['url'])) {

    if ($_GET['url'] === 'home' || $_GET['url'] === 'index') {
        $title = 'Home';
    } elseif ($_GET['url'] === 'about') {
        $title = 'About';
    } else {
        $title = 'Otro';
    }

} else {
    $title = 'Otro';
}
```

Y deberías *sanitizar* todo lo que venga de fuera y se pueda manipular.

Comment: ¿Por qué habría que *sanitizar* en este caso algo que nunca va a mostrarse en pantalla?

Comment: [NUNCA viene de mal](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/140435)  @A.Cedano

Comment: Ya, pero lo que se mostraría en `title` sería una cadena que no depende del dato del `$_GET`, son asignaciones hechas a mano: `Home, About, Otro`. Otra cosa sería si tuvieras que usar el dato del `$_GET` para mostrarlo en el `title`, no es el caso aquí, a eso me refería.

Comment: Ya, y como no sabemos lo que va hacer después de este código... si lo usa o no... es bueno de advertir... y como ya dije nunca viene de mal.

Comment: Genial muchas gracias funciona perfecto. Mi duda ahora, es debe estar ahí o debería aplicar esto en el controlador? en vez que en el fichero header.php de mis vistas que es cómo esta.Perdonar las preguntas, pero estoy aprendiendo a programar php y me surgen muchas dudas de novato... Otra cosa aplico _() para traducir con gettext en la variable, aún no empece hacer las traducciones, haciendolo ahí me las va a coger?

Comment: @a.castro - Me alegro!.. Y a tus preguntas.. Lo suyo sería que lo tengas en tu controlador...y si a la función ` _()`.. te lo cogerá perfectamente.  Mucha suerte y diversión en tu aprendizaje! :)

Comment: No sé si es lo correcto poner esto aquí, pero nadie me contesta a otra duda que tengo, la he formulado, a ver si podéis ayudarme ;) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/358258/diferentes-niveles-de-directorios-con-urls-amigables-en-php-mvc

Comment: Hola @a.castro ! Supongo que tu pregunta es demasiado amplio...Ej. Si tu código funciona pero quieres que haga ahora X y no tienes un problema especifico pues tienes poca probabilidad que te contesten... Haz unos intentos como crees solucionarlo y luego reestructura tu pregunta mas especifico a tu problema.. Suerte! :)